# Gmail Label API returns unspecified 500 error for certain threads

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm updating the labels through the Gmail API using the Python client library, using the following line of code:

```
thread = service.users().threads().modify(userId='me', id=thread_id, body=msg_labels).execute(http=http)
```

This works for most threads, but for certain threads it keeps returning a 500 backend error without any specification. The values for "thread_id" and "msg_labels" are correct, I've triple checked. And as said, it works for other threads through the same line of code. What could be causing this error?

Comment: 500  is a flooding error you are going to fast slow your code down and run the same request again.

Comment: This happens after 5 retries, with a random nr of seconds waiting time in between, always on the same threads.

Comment: You can make a max of 10 requests a second I believe.   If your code gets this error pause it for a second and then run the same request again.  Look into implementing exponential backoff.

Comment: I have exponential backoff implemented. Also, it is running in a task queue which only allows 10 requests per second and it always happens on the same threads. The issue has to be something else.

Comment: Next steps would be to examine the problematic threads and determine if something is unique about them. Might they be chat messages? Any thing else you can identify as unique to these threads (all have certain label maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out for some reason my code was trying to write a Label Id that didn't exist. Don't know how this could happen, since IDs are retrieved from Gmail directly and I didn't delete it myself. Nevertheless it solved the issue.